# Copy files with strange name in python got error 22

Tags: python

I try to copy files with arbitrary names in windows 7 64bit with python using os,  shutil.copy2 and win32.file.copyfile. I copied all the files in certain folders. Sometimes I had ioerror error 22 whenIi had non English
letters in the file names.  In gui, I can easily copy them without any problem with mouse. Any api I should consider? Any suggestion?  Like replacimg all the illegal letter automatically?

Comment: Please share the some code and the exact error.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. A typical file which causes problem is like 'd´caro groove - Mosa (Asi Voce Me Mata).krc'.  when I copy it to different place using shutil.copy2(scrpath,dstpath) for example, I got IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:...  But in windows7 64bit gui, I can certainly copy this file to the same destination path. So if there is a solution, I guess maybe I can import the api the native gui used in windows to do the same job? Maybe? when I list() this file name, I got something like 'd' '?' 'c' 'a' in the result list. So I didn't find a way to replace them

Comment: to continue the previous comment: I guess the question mark means the code is not identified by the system, so I don't find a way to simply match and replace them. A workaround if any may be get a while/black list of legal letters and replace the ones not belong to the white list or belong to the black one. But this method could be very challenging to implement and could be quite unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `shutil.copytree` to copy a folder and all it's content to a destination.

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree('path/to/folder', 'path/to/destination')
```

Comment: Thanks abccd. the actual code does check existing file in the destination folder and compare it with the files from the source folder to see which is newer. So as far as I know, I have to do one file at a time, unless there is a better way to "update" two folders. The example file can definitely be copied in GUI in windows with a mouse, but can't be copied in script. I believe they used different APIs. So do you think there is a way to use the api the GUI used in python script?

Comment: What do you mean by "copied in GUI in Windows", it stands for graphic user interface.

Comment: I meant the file  'd´caro groove - Mosa (Asi Voce Me Mata).krc can be copied and pasted to a different folder by a user in windows GUI using mouse/keyboard just the regular way. I'm not a OS guy, so I guess the expression is not accurate, probably I should say copied using native windows programs like windows explorer. So if we can use the api native windows explore uses or copy it the way a human user does, probably can solve this problem.